# How do you use conditions in lambda expression in java 8?

Tags: java, lambda

I am beginner in programming and I was wondering how you can write lambda expressions with conditions.

```
public interface MathInterface {

    public int retValue(int x);

}

public class k1{
public static void main(String [] args) {
MathInterface f1 = (int x) -> x + 4; // this is a normal lambda expression
    }
}
```

The code above should represent the mathematical function:

f(x) = x + 4.

So my question is how can i write a lambda expression that covers this function:

f(x) =

x/2 (if x is divisble by 2)

((x + 1)/2) (otherwise)

any help appreciated :)

Edit: The answer from @T.J. Crowder was, what I was searching.

> MathInteface f1 = (int x) -> (x % 2 == 0) ? x / 2 : (x + 1) / 2;

Comment: You write an if else statement like normal?

Comment: Also, make sure the if statement is in a block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So my question is how can i write a lambda expression that covers this function...

You either write a lambda with a block body (`{}`) (what I call a "verbose lambda") and use `return`:

```
MathInteface f1 = (int x) -> {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return x / 2;
    }
    return (x + 1) / 2;
};
```

or you use the conditional operator:

```
MathInteface f1 = (int x) -> (x % 2 == 0) ? x / 2 : (x + 1) / 2;
```

(or both).

More details in the [lambda tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: ty the conditional operator was what I was looking for. :)

Comment: That's an example of a perfect answer, nice :)

Answer (score 3):

This return an integer :

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    MathInterface f1 = (int x) -> (x%2 ==0) ? x/2 : ((x + 1)/2); 
}
```

Comment: You are wrong. Result of `(x%2 ==0) ? x/2 : ((x + 1)/2)` is even number.

Comment: He ask for x/2 (if x is divisble by 2), so, what did i wronG?

Comment: `x / 2` is not equals to `x % 2`

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I followed what the parenthesis asked for (if x is divisble by 2), and a number is divisible by 2 if (x%2 ==0)

Comment: Another comment... Look at the anser above mine:
(int x) -> x % 2 == 0 ?  x/2 : (x+1)/2; Is exactly what I did, but only that he wrote faster than me and published first, or maybe we did amost at the same time, whatever... His answer was well accepted, why mine is not to you?

Comment: Ok. 5%2 -> 1, so execute ((5+1)/2) -> 3. 8%2 -> 0, so now execute 8/2 -> 4. In each case we have even number as result.

Comment: Excuse me... what? ((5+1)/2) -> 3. 8%2 -> 0, what? sorry I'm really trying to follow you but I can't...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143626/discussion-between-bor-laze-and-damian-lattenero).

Answer (score 3):

For that particular function, a ternary would be possible.

```
(int x) -> x % 2 == 0 ?  x/2 : (x+1)/2;
```

Otherwise, make a block

```
(int x) -> {
    // if... else 
}
```

Inside of which, you `return` the value

Comment: I bother you for a moment, do you think my answer is diferent at yours in some point? because I am maybe a little confused, or I did something wrong that I cannot see

Comment: I can't control how others vote. Looks the same to me

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, and the patient, I thought I was losing my mind ajajajaj. Nos vemos luego por aqui

Comment: @Damian you are missing how to put an actual if statement in a lambda

Answer (score 1):

**If you feel like being cheeky**, you can actually *exploit* integer division here.

When you divide two integers, the part of the number after the decimal point is automatically dropped. So `5 / 2 = 2`.

For that reason, you can get away with just the odd number case:

```
MathInterface f1 = (int x) -> (x + 1) / 2;
```

In the case of even numbers, when they are incremented they will become odd, resulting in a `.5` which will be dropped automatically.

---

I wouldn't recommend this approach because it's not clear you (the original programmer) are aware what's going on. Being explicit is better.

Comment: But if 5 is input, expected output is 3. If 4 is input, output should be 2... This doesn't match the function in the question

Comment: Regardless, this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @cricket_007  *"my question is how can i write a lambda expression that covers this function"* Explain how.

Comment: Try quoting the title of the question or the first sentence?